# How to combine table/chart with (Google) Maps (stats)

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

I want to use `Google Maps` or another Map like `Openstreetmap` to make an interactive site where people can see the stats of crime in their own area... I want to put in these stats by myself via the backend. The front-end must be something like this:

http://www.police.act.gov.au/crime-and-safety/crime-statistics.aspx

Where do I start with this? Is this a `polygon`? I have read the `Google Maps API` but I could not find a clue to make something like this. How did they put the stats in it? How can I color the area's and divide them? What did they use? Any direction would be very welcome.

PS: I want to have a detailed map. So no countries or cities, but the area's in a certain city have to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest is that first study the developer documentation thoroughly for Google API v3.Basics will help a lot.
For pointers to your needs, you can get help in defining polygons and coloring them at this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons and also check out the demo examples in the code.
For a 3 point polygon, here is an example https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

You can define your polygons by adding points around your area. There are many tools available to find your pointer locations like http://martinove.dk/maptools/polytool/

In order to potray data, you can use markerclusterer. These examples can help:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/